# QTableView: how to hover an entire row on mouse over?

Tags: windows, qt, hover, row, qtableview

I subclassed QTableView, QAbstractTableModel, and QItemDelegate. I am able to hover a single cell on mouse over:

```
void SchedulerDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    ...

    if(option.showDecorationSelected &&(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected))
{
    QColor color(255,255,130,100);
    QColor colorEnd(255,255,50,150);
    QLinearGradient gradient(option.rect.topLeft(),option.rect.bottomRight());
    gradient.setColorAt(0,color);
    gradient.setColorAt(1,colorEnd);
    QBrush brush(gradient);
    painter->fillRect(option.rect,brush);
}

    ...
}
```

... but I cannot figure out, how to hover an entire row. Can Someone help me with sample codes?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to tell Qt to highlight the entire row on mouse hover, no luck..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTableView How can I highlight the entire row for mouse hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565930/qtableview-how-can-i-highlight-the-entire-row-for-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways..

> 1) You can use delegates to draw the row background...
>         You will need to set the row to highlight in the delegate and based on that,
>          do the highlighting.
>
> 2) Catch the signal of current row. Iterate over the items in that row
>   and 
>          set background for each item.

you can also tried style sheet:

```
QTableView::item:hover {
    background-color: #D3F1FC;
}
```

Hope, It will usefull to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation,it works well.First you should subclass QTableView/QTabWidget ,emit a signal to QStyledItemDelegate in mouseMoveEvent/dragMoveEvent function .This signal will send the hovering index.

In QStyledItemDelegate ,use a member variable hover_row_(changed in a slot bind to above signal) to tell paint function which row is be hovered.

Here is the code examaple:

```
//1: Tableview :
void TableView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());
    emit hoverIndexChanged(index);
    ...
}
//2.connect signal and slot
    connect(this,SIGNAL(hoverIndexChanged(const QModelIndex&)),delegate_,SLOT(onHoverIndexChanged(const QModelIndex&)));

//3.onHoverIndexChanged
void TableViewDelegate::onHoverIndexChanged(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    hoverrow_ = index.row();
}

//4.in Delegate paint():
void TableViewDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
...
    if(index.row() == hoverrow_)
    {
        //HERE IS HOVER COLOR
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, kHoverItemBackgroundcColor);
    }
    else
    {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, kItemBackgroundColor);
    }
...
}
```