# QTableView How can I highlight the entire row for mouse hover?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtableview

The selection behavior is set to select rows, but only the hovered cell is highlighted. Is there any way to highlight the entire row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways..

> 1) You can use delegates to draw the row background...
>         You will need to set the row to highlight in the delegate and based on that,
>          do the highlighting.
>
> 2) Catch the signal of current row. Iterate over the items in that row
>   and 
>          set background for each item.

Hope, It will usefull to you guys.

Comment: .Could you please give some more explain on first approach

Comment: Not very helpful. Why don't you give an example?

Answer (score 10):

First, you subclass `QTableWidget/QTableView` and reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` and `leaveEvent`.

In `custom_table_widget.cpp`, you should have:

```
...
CustomTableWidget::CustomTableWidget(QWidget *parent) :
  QTableWidget(parent)
{
  setMouseTracking(true);  // receives mouse move events even if no buttons are pressed.
}

void CustomTableWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  // detect where the mouse cursor is relative to our custom table widget
  QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());
  emit hoverIndexChanged(index);
}

void CustomTableWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
  // detect when the mouse cursor leaves our custom table widget
  emit leaveTableEvent();
  viewport()->update();
}
...
```

Next, you subclass `QStyledItemDelegate`. Reimplement `paint` method and add two slots to modify the hovered row. In `row_hover_delegate.cpp`, you should have:

```
...
void RowHoverDelegate::onHoverIndexChanged(const QModelIndex& item) {
  hovered_row_ = item.row();
}

void RowHoverDelegate::onLeaveTableEvent() {
  hovered_row_ = -1;
}

void RowHoverDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                                  const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                  const QModelIndex &index) const {
  QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
  if(index.row() == hovered_row_) {
    opt.state |= QStyle::State_MouseOver;
  } else {
    opt.state &= ~QStyle::State_MouseOver;
  }
  QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
}
...
```

Finally, connect the the signals/slots and set the item delegate:

```
connect(my_custom_table_widget, 
        &CustomTableWidget::hoverIndexChanged,
        my_row_hover_delegate,
        &RowHoverDelegate::onHoverIndexChanged);
connect(my_custom_table_widget, 
        &CustomTableWidget::leaveTableEvent,
        my_row_hover_delegate,
        &RowHoverDelegate::onLeaveTableEvent);

my_custom_table_widget->setItemDelegate(my_row_hover_delegate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it wasn't really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

An old question but as I managed to solve it using only the delegate, here my solution for anybody stumbling across the same problem. This is in PyQt5, but should be easy to convert to c++.

```
class HoverDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Define the hover colour
        self.hoverBackground = QBrush(QColor('#F5F5F5'))
        # Initiate variables to invalid model indices
        self.currentHovered = QModelIndex()
        self.previousHovered = QModelIndex()

    def initStyleOption(self, option, modelIndex):
        super().initStyleOption(option, modelIndex)

        # Cache model indices
        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            if modelIndex.row() != self.currentHovered.row():
                self.previousHovered = self.currentHovered
                self.currentHovered = modelIndex

        # Set background brush if we're on a hover row
        if modelIndex.row() == self.currentHovered.row():
            option.backgroundBrush = self.hoverBackground


    def paint(self, painter, option, modelIndex):
        # Standard paint event takes care of painting the hover background
        # if defined in initStyleOption 
        super().paint(painter, option, modelIndex)

        # Remove the hover background from the previously hovered row
        # by requesting update of all cells of the previously hovered row
        if self.previousHovered.isValid():
            view = self.parent()
            col = 0
            index = self.previousHovered.siblingAtColumn(col)

            while index.isValid():
                view.update(index)
                col += 1
                index = index.siblingAtColumn(col)

            # Reset to an invalid index
            self.previousHovered = QModelIndex()
```